# What exactly does this Hadoop command performed in the shell?

Tags: hadoop

I am absolutly new in Apache Hadoop and I am following a video course.

So I have correctly installed **Hadoop 1.2.1** on a linux Ubuntu virtual machine.

After the installation the instructor perform this command in the shell:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

to see that Hadoop is working and that it is correctly installed.

But what exactly does this command?

Comment: Umm. 1.2.1 was released in 2013... You may want to find a new course since hadoop has changed a bit since then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command runs a grep job defined inside hadoop examples jar file (containing map, reduce and driver code) with input folder to search for specified in `input` folder in hdfs while `output` is the folder where output after searching for patter would be in that file while `dfs[a-z.]+` is a regular expression which you are saying to grep for in input.

Comment: I am new to Hadoop too. Is the `grep` the bash `grep`? Or it's just something defined with this name inside the `jar` file? Is it calling the bash `grep`?